# itext html pre tag formatting issue with parseToElementList

Tags: html, itext

I'm creating a simple pdf with itextpdf in Java. I need to add html enclosed in pre tags to only some of the cells (comes from a JTextPane where the pre tag works perfectly).
I do this so the user can preserve their tabs, spaces, bold, italic etc. when they generate a pdf.

**This is the html that gets parsed (directly from JTextPane, then cleaned by JSoup):**

```
<html>\n 
<head></head>\n
 <body>\n
  <pre><b>SomePerson Surname \n\n

</b>10 Acme Drive<b>
\nEmail:\tsomeperson@gmail.com</b></pre> \n
 </body>\n
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
**This is the output:**

```
**SomePerson Surname**    
10 Acme Drive    
**Email:**    
someperson@gmail.com
```

This is how is should look (JTextPane renders it just fine):

```
**SomePerson Surname**

10 Acme Drive
**Email:**  someperson@gmail.com
```

Here is my simple method to add an html element using itextpdf:

```
private void CreateHTMLPdfCell(PdfPTable topTable, String html, int horizontalAlignment, int border, int colSpan) {

    String CSS = "pre {\n" +
    "    display: inline;\n" +
    "    margin: 0;\n" +
    "}";
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
    cell.setBorder(border);
    cell.setColspan(colSpan);   

    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);          
    Whitelist WHITELIST = Whitelist.relaxed();
    Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(WHITELIST);
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document clean = cleaner.clean(doc);

    try {
        for (Element e : XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(clean.html(), CSS)) {
            cell.addElement(e);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
    }
    topTable.addCell(cell);
}
```